# Showing input parameters on design surface

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I am trying to figure out how to desing my own WF4 Activity representations.  For instance, I have an activity called AssignMemberDates that has 2 IN Arguments:  a DataType (from a List<>) and a RecordType (also from a List<>).  I have 10 different DateTypes and 3 different RecordTypes.  Instead of creating 30 Activities I want the single Activity.  When I drag it to the WF surface and assign my 2 inputs I would like something more than the generic Activity container showing.  Let's see if I can (using ASCII) draw this out...

What I get now:

```
+-------------------------------+
| [ICON] AssignMemberDates      |  
+-------------------------------+
```

What I want:

```
+-------------------------------+
| [ICON] AssignMemberDates      |  
|   Pending / BenefitMonth      |  
+-------------------------------+
```

Does that make sense?  I know I need to create a XAML but I am at a loss for how to capture the InArguments (enums) and display them as text.  I am **NOT** looking to make this an editor input.  I just want to see the InArguments in the activity on the design surface.

**Update:**

I am using enums on the InArguments so the developers down the road are constrained on what they can enter on the designer properties.  It is as simple as:

```
public InArgument<DateTypeList> DateType { get; set; }
public InArgument<RecordTypeList> RecordType { get; set; }
```

I do know how to get a string from my enums.  I am a neophyte at designers and am asking for help with that.  I don't know how to display the property values on the design surface and there seems to be a ton of display "widgets" I **could** use.

I've started out with the following XAML but am not getting very far - and it looks like this is more of an input similar to what you see in the properties tab:

```
<sap:ActivityDesigner x:Class="PSI.Workflow.Activities.SouthCarolina.SC1AssignMemberDateDesigner"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
    xmlns:sapv="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.View;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="86" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <StackPanel>
        <sapv:ExpressionTextBox MaxLines="1" ></sapv:ExpressionTextBox>
        <sapv:ExpressionTextBox MaxLines="1"></sapv:ExpressionTextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</sap:ActivityDesigner>
```

I don't know how to take the 2 input parameter values and display them.  If I was in HTML I would simply create a <label/> control and then supply the value I wanted during page load.  I also do not want the display elements stacked but rather side-by-side separated with a "/".

Does this make more sense?

**Update 2:**

1. Why am I using enums? - We use enums throughout the code base to constrain inputs to known values.  We do not want to use "magic strings" and all of our code base, 2 million lines plus, depends on the use of hundreds of enums.  Converting enums to strings is no problem.  We also want to constrain the inputs to this activity to known values (enums).  For example:

   ```
   public InArgument<DateTypeList> DateType { get; set; }
   public InArgument<RecordTypeList> RecordType { get; set; }

   protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
   {
   // In Arguments...
   var dateType = DateType.Get(context);
   var recordType = RecordType.Get(context);
   // Let's get what we need from the context...
   var member = context.Member();
   var mtd = context.MemberTransaction();
   var cutoffDates = context.CutoffDates();
   DateTime? startDate = null;
   DateTime? endDate = null;

   switch (dateType)
   {
       case DateTypeList.ARC:
           startDate = Helpers.GetDate(cutoffDates, CutoffDateType.EnrollmentStart, mtd.assignable.ToBoolean()).AddYears(1);
           break;

       case DateTypeList.AutoAssignment:
           startDate = Helpers.GetDate(cutoffDates, CutoffDateType.AutoAssignment, mtd.assignable.ToBoolean());
           break;

   }
   Helpers.AssignDate(ref member, dateType, recordType, startDate.Value, endDate);
   ```

   }
2. No, I've never tried to design something like this.  I do not have XAMLX experience and I am starting from scratch.  I just want to simply transfer the string representation of the enum to the designer surface.  This way, when we review the workflow with non-technical people it is clearly displayed on the activity itself what values were passed in during setup of the activity.

Comment: Unfortunately its not clear what you want to do here...  Sounds like you want to just show the state of the Activity in the designer as it is set in the properties window.  But I don't know if you don't know HOW to create a designer, or if you are having trouble converting from an Enum value to a string... Also, why InArgument<YourEnum>?  You only need that if you're binding to a variable or argument...

Comment: I wish your comment was more helpful.

Comment: I wish you would [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'll take a whack.  You'll probably have to leave me comments to get additional info.

First, your activity doesn't *have* to make all of its properties InArgument's.  That's only if the value of the property changes at *runtime*.  If, like it appears in your case, those property values are set at *design time* (when they are dropped on the design surface), then you can just make them regular properties.

```
public sealed class MyActivity : NativeActivity
{
    public DateTypeList DateType { get; set; }
    public RecordTypeList RecordType { get; set; }
    // snip
```

To display the value of these, there are a couple different ways.  Three TextBlocks, first bound to DateTime, the second has a literal slash "\", and the third is bound to RecordType.  Or, you could use a MultiBinding and simply set up a StringFormat with the slash.

This is pretty simple.  Here's some xaml-like pseudocode which demonstrates (i.e., its not tested)

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{{Binding ModelItem.DateType}" />
    <TextBlock Text="\" />
    <TextBlock Text="{{Binding ModelItem.RecordType }" />
</StackPanel>
```

The second

```
<TextBlock>    
    <TextBlock.Text>        
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}\{1}">            
            <Binding Path="ModelItem.DateType" />
            <Binding Path="ModelItem.DateType" />            
        </MultiBinding> 
    </TextBlock.Text>       
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will endeavor to try these out later today.  I can sometimes squeeze in 30 minutes for this type work while under our delivery deadlines.  Also please note, about 80% of the time the inputs are design time decisions.  The other 20% of the time they are runtime inputs.  Also inheriting a full blown system with specific ways of passing data somewhat constricts our options.  I will also look intot he regular property vs the In/Out properties (arguments).